# Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member?

Tags: c#, assemblies, yaf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member - SecurityRuleSet.Level2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055792/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-securityruleset-lev)

> Inheritance security rules violated
>   while overriding member:
>   'YAF.Types.Flags.FlagsBase.GetObjectData(System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'.
>   Security accessibility of the
>   overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method
>   being overriden.

I already did resolve this by adding the following line to every assembly:

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

But I don't really have a clue why this happened. I mean I understand the error and thus the solution, but why haven't I ever come up with this error and in trying to get this solution up and running it was one of the absolute first things I needed to hack

Comment: I'm not looking for another solution to the problem, I'm looking to understand why it arises.