# Issue with installing Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

In order to set up a website running on Orchard CMS,I extracted the contents of the zip file downloaded from http://www.orchardproject.net (version 1.6) and uploaded them to my host.However,After trying to view the site on the browser,I got the following exception:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 
>   'log4net.Util.ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.Ser>ializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility >of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being >overriden.

Having done a lot of search online,I realized that the problem was due to the fact that an Orchard website needs to be run in a Full trust mode on the server.But again the problem is that my host won't allow such a thing for security concerns.
So,I wonder if someone know if I get the issue sorted out by making a change to the source code of Orchard project like setting a security attribute in the assembly file or anything like that as described here:
[Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member - SecurityRuleSet.Level2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055792/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-securityruleset-le)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Orchard works in medium trust if I remember correctly. Full trust just gives better performance etc :)

Comment: As I understood,It used to work in partial trust mood but not anymore.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a conscious decision from the team not to support partial trust any more. Microsoft doesn't recommend partial trust any more.

Comment: It appears that Orchard no longer supports partial trust since it's not recommended by Microsoft and the only thing I can do to get the site up and running is to change to a host that supports Full trust mode.