# Getting "Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Antlr.Runtime.RecognitionException.GetObjectData..." with NHibernate 4.1.0

Tags: c#, exception, nhibernate, .net-4.5, antlr3

I'm getting this error from Nhibernate 4.1.0 in release mode with c# ASP.NET application on .NET 4.5.1:

```
Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Antlr.Runtime.RecognitionException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
```

Being Antl3 an included dll I can't figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055792/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-securityruleset-le) pointed me in the right direction.

I needed to have an Antl3 version which had GetObjectData marked with SecurityCriticalAttribute and that was clearly not the version shipped with NHibernate 4.1.0 sources, so I got Antl3 sources from [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/tree/fd955a8a6ea4f8726779c9abd9921479b303806d) and looked at RecognitionException under Antl3.Runtime.net40-client and have seen it was correct:

```
        [SecurityCritical]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
```

So I've bult it, replaced the produced dll in the NHibernate-4.1.0.GA-src\lib\net folder and et voila, now the application runs fine

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that your application demands "more trust". You can change the trust level for your application by adding `<trust level="Full" />` in your `web.config` (inside `system.web`).

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
<system.web>
```

More about ASP.NET Trust levels can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wyts434y(v=vs.100)).