# Unity 5.8: registration by convention "Inheritance security rules violated"

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have updated Unity 4 container to Unity 5.8 but I have problem with registration by convention in this version. It completly doesn't work. Fresh project, installed following packages:

```
Install-Package Unity.Container -v 5.8.7
Install-Package Unity.RegistrationByConvention -v 2.1.7
```

super simple code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer uc = new UnityContainer();

        uc.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), (c) => WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface(c));
    }
}
```

and it gives exception

```
System.TypeLoadException: „Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 
Unity.RegistrationByConvention.Exceptions.DuplicateTypeMappingException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
```

I have no idea what is wrong, it used to work in previous version. Does any know how to use registration by convenion in new Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055792/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-securityruleset-le), this seems to be a problem with Unity.RegistrationByConvention. Their `DuplicateTypeMappingException` should have the `SecurityCriticalAttribute` on `GetObjectData` which is indeed present in `System.Exception` as stated in the exception you posted.

Meanwhile, I think it should suffice to only register your own types, not just everything from every library in the project.

Comment: yup, it was a problem in Unity.RegistrationByConvention, luckily older version (2.1.5) works ok. It is not always worth to update all packages :)